# "To be headed for" and "To be headed over to"

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, word-usage

Can these expressions be used just about interchangeably for all but the most formal prose, or is there a subtle difference to them?

E.g.

He *is headed over to* the garage.

He *is headed for* the garage.

Comment: They mean the same thing, but neither are particularly idiomatic. As usual, you focus on non-standard usages. Most people would say *"He's **heading** for the garage."*

Comment: @FumbleFingers I believe the preference to be regional dialect.  *Headed over to* is used with quite a bit of frequency in the Northeastern US.  *Headed for* is more popular, though.

Comment: @DavidM That's right! This diagram shows it particularly well:https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+headed+for%2Cis+heading+for&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=5&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20headed%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20heading%20for%3B%2Cc0

Comment: This stock phrase "As far as your English variety goes" - I would consider losing that.  First off, your English variety contrasts to say . . . your German variety, or Lithuanian variety.  It sounds like you're describing a sub-type of dog breed.  It you want to use this construct, you would say *variety of English*.  Or, better yet, use the term *dialect* here.  It is the proper term for this.

Comment: If you target your specific usage more precisely by including *He* at the front, you'll discover that [*on average*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=He+is+headed+for%2CHe+is+heading+for&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=20&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHe%20is%20headed%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CHe%20is%20heading%20for%3B%2Cc0) even US usage favours *heading*. (And that comparatively speaking, Brits don't use *headed for* enough to even chart.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers That is absolutely true.  Heading over is more common to be certain.  I missed your meaning before.  I thought you were contrasting over vs. for, not heading vs. headed.  But, headed is used with enough frequency in the US to register.

Comment: @DavidM I did use the term of "dialect" once, to which I wash asked "What do you mean by "dialect"? Apparently some native find the "offensive", which is why I switched to "variety". Now I'm feeling totally at a loss about what term to choose..

Comment: What you would do is:  Ask your question.  And, then ask, are there differences based upon dialectical differences (*e.g.* AmE, BrE, etc.)?  No one will give you static about that.

Comment: @David M You mean "dialectal" by "dialectical", uh?

Comment: @NourishedGourmet Yes, sorry.  I did mean dialectal.  I do that a lot, for some reason I seem to type dialectical instead of dialectal.

Comment: @FumbleFingers But if you switch from "He" to "he" at the front, you'll discover that the graph shows a different result: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+is+heading+for%2Che+is+headed+for&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Che%20is%20heading%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20is%20headed%20for%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @DavidM No worries, David.

Comment: @@NourishedGourmet: I guess [*We're heading for*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=We're+headed+for%2CWe're+heading+for&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=20&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CWe%20%27re%20headed%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CWe%20%27re%20heading%20for%3B%2Cc0) *NGrams at dawn* then. Well, that's how ***I'll*** be getting there - I guess you'll be *headed for the the NGram duelling ground*, doubtless with David *headed over there* to be your squire. May the best NGrammer win, but I think I have time (and trends) on my side! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are typically used interchangeably.

There can be an inferred subtextual difference, though.

**Headed over to** *can* impart an airy quality.  It seems to suggest he'll get there when he gets there.  (He might stop for a cup of coffee, along the way.)  **I want to make clear, that this is NOT necessarily implied by this.**  It is just a feeling you *might* get upon hearing this phrase.

**Headed for** implies that he is going in the direction of the garage as we speak.

Comment: Well, at least I've learned something from this question. The available evidence suggests to me that *headed over/for* are heading for terminal decline in perhaps just a few decades, but as of now the form is alive and well in the US. It doesn't exactly sound "weird" to me, but I must admit it does sound just faintly "rustic/folksy".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yeah, in reading it, it didn't even register as odd to me.  Again, *two countries separated by a common language!*

Comment: ...I'm not sure, but I more than suspect there's a general shift towards *-ing* forms over *-ed* forms in many such contexts, that's probably common to US and UK usage.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I guess it represents our desire to live in the moment.  To me, the difference would be:  I'm heading over there (right now).  I'm headed over there (after I finish eating).  But, this distinction doesn't hold up for me when using *headed for* or *heading for*.  Those mean right now unless specifically modified.

Comment: I wouldn't normally bother to make that fine distinction anyway, since context would usually cover it perfectly well. If I say *"I'm heading over the pub"* while I'm still at home eating my dinner, I'd be somewhat scathing of anyone pointing out that I wasn't in fact heading *anywhere* at that precise moment. Just as I don't really bother to distinguish *"I'm [doing...]"* from *"I'll be [doing...]"* in many contexts. Nor would I care to be told I'm going ***to*** the pub, rather than ***over=above*** it.

Comment: Just to note: In BE. there are contexts such as "he's headed for promotion" which can't be adapted to the other form.

Comment: @duck Why can't it be?  He's heading for promotion works just fine.  Or do you mean *headed over* to promotion is not used?  To which I'd say, I agree (but we use the same headed for in AmE)

Comment: @David- We agree! I take your point about headed for, that works just as well this side of the pond.